# Extracting checksum from singe line

Tags: linux, perl, sed, awk, grep

I'm trying to get the MD5 of the specified Java package by going through: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-binaries-checksum-1956892.html

However, that entire table is just a one-liner in the `HTML code`, so that makes it a little trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally went with `sed`:

```
$ curl -s http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javase8-binaries-checksum-2133161.html | sed -nr 's|.*>jdk-8-linux-x64.tar.gz</td><td>(<*[^<]*).*|\1|p'
7e9e5e5229c6603a4d8476050bbd98b1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagded your question with `sed`, `grep`, etc. I am assuming you'll do it from Linux. So you can use Perl's one liner for this.

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e "$\ = $/; print for get('http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-binaries-checksum-1956892.html') =~ m|<td>([a-f0-9]{32})</td>|g;"
```

This is first downloading the html into `$_` variable. Then its parsing the hash from the `<td>` tags using regex. Pretty simple, yet powerful!

Comment: Hmm, that's producing `Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near ");"`
`Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`.

Comment: @Det I have updated the answer. Previous one I have tested at my windows's Perl and worked. This one should work on both!

Comment: Great, but that lists all of them, while I need only the md5sums of the requested package.

Comment: @Det for requested package just change the `m|...|g` with `m|<td>jdk-7u51-solaris-x64.tar.gz</td><td>([a-f0-9]{32})</td>|g;` Here you can change the package name.

Answer (score 1):

This is from your request, using curl + gnu grep

```
curl -s http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-binaries-checksum-1956892.html|grep -Po '(?<=<td>)[a-f0-9]{32}'
```

#### Explanation

- `curl` command will get the hmtl to stout and pipe to grep command
- `grep -Po '(?<=<td>)[a-f0-9]{32}'` is a positive look-behind assertion, get only md5 sum. It should be supported in JAVA as well.

#### For your new request, I recommend to use `lynx` (text-based web browser). So if you have it ready, run this command:

```
lynx -dump http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-binaries-checksum-1956892.html |grep jdk-7u51-solaris-sparc.tar.Z 

  jdk-7u51-solaris-sparc.tar.Z           eb2ebfe3217d306f0ee549edc1875a93
```

#### explanation

1) `lynx` is text-base web browser, here are its homepage and related introduces.

```
http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/index.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser
```

2) `lynx with -dump` option will take a snapshot on that webpage with reserved format. I used it as `html2txt` tool.  Here is the sample webpage for your reference.

```
Java SE Binaries Checksum

Checksum for Java SE 7u51 binaries

                  Filename                          MD5 Checksum
   jdk-7u51-linux-arm-vfp-hflt.tar.gz     80e14facc0aa784f44d8f142025dd020
   jdk-7u51-linux-arm-vfp-sflt.tar.gz     a2965bc7591a257da8c09772f15f6195
   jdk-7u51-linux-i586.rpm                457fb449a4486860ec5bde6c28ce8ec4
   jdk-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz             909d353c1caf6b3b54cc20767a7778ef
   jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm                 c523e7339d925c1e6c5994813f7c9e86
   jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz              764f96c4b078b80adaa5983e75470ff2
   jdk-7u51-macosx-x64.dmg                73e9cc08d590021706e117c81bc9a4a9
   jdk-7u51-solaris-i586.tar.Z            9127418718bec67a4146c5dc1da15155
   jdk-7u51-solaris-i586.tar.gz           cd914ce06ff537a3acb249d23baf6244
   jdk-7u51-solaris-x64.tar.Z             5ee1d6b0d607f80ac0e376485d70e9e4
   jdk-7u51-solaris-x64.tar.gz            6e00698dc72b707580f11c4e0288ab2b
   jdk-7u51-solaris-sparc.tar.Z           eb2ebfe3217d306f0ee549edc1875a93
   jdk-7u51-solaris-sparc.tar.gz          60bdb8a9b19db80848d8b6c27466276b
   jdk-7u51-solaris-sparcv9.tar.Z         9da60e11238b288a5339688acd64abe0
   jdk-7u51-solaris-sparcv9.tar.gz        1cb3c5e8cdcad6c9bfaffc3874187786
   jdk-7u51-windows-i586.exe              121b2a740e18bc00b0e13f4537e5f1bc
   jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe               d1367410be659f1b47e554e7bd011ea0
   jre-7u51-linux-i586.rpm                28d0ee36020023904e64afeebc9555cc
   jre-7u51-linux-i586.tar.gz             f133f125ca93acef3f70d1912cc2f4b0
   jre-7u51-linux-x64.rpm                 d914baffa3cb378a6054969d7d9bbbd0
   jre-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz              1f6a93cc5ef5f66bb01bc39fd731cd9f
   jre-7u51-macosx-x64.dmg                b66f5af9e3607dc5727f752a9d28b7fd
   jre-7u51-macosx-x64.tar.gz             cbd57817ea302be8b2c44968e130bb9b
   jre-7u51-solaris-i586.tar.gz           61c5daacea83dc1b267e84bf21e22645
   jre-7u51-solaris-x64.tar.gz            f03c4d69124f0595db32e20f2aa517f2
   jre-7u51-solaris-sparc.tar.gz          f9b459dabd97428e95275e259422d6a7
   jre-7u51-solaris-sparcv9.tar.gz        32cb98b794bc01ca79f1b6e51fe09c9c
   jre-7u51-windows-i586-iftw.exe         5e8cb14f5264af82f66008306e56eaa8
   jre-7u51-windows-i586.exe              1af9e2aa8264b023404a76d3fb6751fe
   jre-7u51-windows-i586.tar.gz           3921c19528d180902939b9f4c9ac92f1
   jre-7u51-windows-x64.exe               b0f3a9c0f4c2c66127223ba3644b54f6
   jre-7u51-windows-x64.tar.gz            1931de2341f22408be9d6639205675c9
   server-jre-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz       c5a034f4222bac326101799bcb20509c
   server-jre-7u51-solaris-i586.tar.gz    955d2884960124e93699008236d736fe
   server-jre-7u51-solaris-x64.tar.gz     b858f9326986cfc7f7cceb4b166c0bfa
   server-jre-7u51-solaris-sparc.tar.gz   04c708b162e6210b546b0eef188d4adb
   server-jre-7u51-solaris-sparcv9.tar.gz 7ae0e51f5836289d71ad614326c5e9c8
   server-jre-7u51-windows-x64.tar.gz     4d9855b5b54cbae9d04318eae9b8e11e
   Use the md5sum command line utility on Linux to verify the integrity of
   the downloaded file.
   Use the md5 command line utility on Mac OS X to verify the integrity of
   the downloaded file
   See the following articles for guidance on how to verify these
   checksums on other platforms:
     * Microsoft Windows: [29]Availability and description of the File
       Checksum Integrity Verifier utility

   Left Curve

                             Java SDKs and Tools

   Right Curve
   [30]Java SE
   [31]Java EE and Glassfish
   [32]Java ME
   [33]JavaFX
   [34]Java Card
   [35]NetBeans IDE
   [36]Java Mission Control
   Left Curve

                               Java Resources
```

Comment: This still only lists _all_ of the MD5 sums, while I'd only want to print one at a time (for the specified name). I've edited my question to be more precise.

Comment: I updated my answer, and recommend to use exist tool `lynx` to do your job.

Comment: got your point. Finally, what solution you went for? Did you try lynx?

Comment: Well, I didn't want to install/use an external program, so I just went with `sed`. Cool trick the `lynx -dump`, though. Never knew it was that useful.